# How to convert the date time in given format to epoch using python?

Tags: python, epoch

I have datetime in following format:

> Tuesday, 14 February 2017, 4:10 PM

how to convert it to epoch using python ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime` from the standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "Tuesday, 14 February 2017, 4:10 PM"
print(datetime.strptime(date, "%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p").timestamp())
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for `strptime()` behavior and format codes.